# apache chemistry with Alfresco ACLs coming as null

Tags: java

I am using alfresco as repository and using Apache chemistry to fetch the content from the repository.

In one of my implementation I am trying to retrieve the folders and files created or have access by a specific user.

I am using the Operation Context to fetch all the values which are coming fine but when I try to get the ACLs of that object(folder/file) I am getting null response.
Below are some of the code snippet of my approach, could somebody help me understanding if i am doing something wrong or someother approach to get the ACLs.

1)

```
    {  SPIMObject spimObject = null;


    OperationContext opcontext = getSpimObjectOperationContext(cmisSession);
            opcontext.setIncludeAcls(true);
            ArrayList<SPIMObject> spimObjectList = new ArrayList<SPIMObject>();
            ItemIterable<CmisObject> results =     `enter code here`getSpimRoot(cmi

sSession).getChildren(opcontext);
for(CmisObject result : results){
spimObject=getResultObjectDetails(cmisSession, opcontext, result);
            spimObject.setIsSharedItem(false);
            spimObjectList.add(spimObject);
}
return spimObjectList;}
```

2) //Calling the get ACL method

```
spimObject.setShareObjectAcl(getSpimObjectAcls(result));
```

3) //Method

```
public List<SPIMObjectAcl> getSpimObjectAcls(CmisObject cmisObject)
            throws Exception {

        List<SPIMObjectAcl> spimAceList = new ArrayList<SPIMObjectAcl>();
        List<Ace> aceList = null;
        aceList = cmisObject.getAcl().getAces();  // Null response here.
 }
```

4) //Operation Context method

```
public OperationContext getSpimObjectOperationContext(Session cmisSession) {

        OperationContext operationContext = null;

        if (cmisSession != null) {
            operationContext = cmisSession.getDefaultContext();
        }

        if (operationContext == null) {
            log.debug("found operation context null  for : cmisSession :"
                    + cmisSession);
            operationContext = new OperationContextImpl();
        }

        operationContext.setIncludeAcls(true);

        return operationContext;
    }
```